# AES - how do I convert a string(byte string) to a byte(byte string)?

Tags: python-3.x, aes

I am creating an encrypted chat program using python and AES. I have some working code that I gathered from https://riptutorial.com/python/example/18926/symmetric-encryption-using-pycrypto

```
import hashlib
import math
import os
import base64

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

IV_SIZE = 16    # 128 bit, fixed for the AES algorithm
KEY_SIZE = 32   # 256 bit meaning AES-256, can also be 128 or 192 bits
SALT_SIZE = 16  # This size is arbitrary

cleartext = b'Lorem ipsum'
password = b'highly secure encryption password'
salt = os.urandom(SALT_SIZE)
derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                          dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
key = derived[IV_SIZE:]

encrypted = salt + AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).encrypt(cleartext)

print(encrypted)
############################################
# edit here: it is being pulled as a string instead of a byte string
encrypted = str(encrypted)
###########################################

# encrypted and enc2 should be the same, except for the salt.


encryptedString = base64.encodebytes(encrypted)

print(encryptedString) # <- this is what can be stored and fetched from mySQL

encrypted = base64.decodebytes(encryptedString) # <- get the bytes back

salt = encrypted[0:SALT_SIZE]
derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                          dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
key = derived[IV_SIZE:]
cleartext = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).decrypt(encrypted[SALT_SIZE:])

    print(cleartext)
```

When I run the code above I get a TypeError: *expected bytes-like object, not str*

I have tried a few methods:

1. bytes(encrypted, 'utf-8')
   The problem with this method is that it ended up encrypting the string again.
2. encrypted.encode()
   This does the same thing as before.

How do I convert a string(byte string) to a byte(byte string) without having to manually copy and paste the string and place a b in front of it?

Comment: Encoding is not encryption. It may look like gibberish but it is not.

Comment: I don't understand. I am trying to avoid having to manually copy and pasting the output of the encryption. How do I pass it through as pure code?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the example you linked to and it worked fine, so it seems like your challenge is storing binary data into strings and recovering the bytes again. Arbitrary bytes are not going to be valid unicode strings, so you'll need to transcode them into a valid text representation, such as Base64.

Here's some code that is probably close to what you want:

```
import hashlib
import math
import os
import base64

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

IV_SIZE = 16    # 128 bit, fixed for the AES algorithm
KEY_SIZE = 32   # 256 bit meaning AES-256, can also be 128 or 192 bits
SALT_SIZE = 16  # This size is arbitrary

cleartext = b'Lorem ipsum'
password = b'highly secure encryption password'
salt = os.urandom(SALT_SIZE)
derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                              dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
key = derived[IV_SIZE:]

encrypted = salt + AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).encrypt(cleartext)

print(encrypted)

enc2=b'J\x82K\xf6\x10j\x06\xdbK\xd6\xf2\xc2Y\x98\xb9\x16\xb7\x0f\xfa\xb9\x19?\x9ak\xa1\xd5\xc4'

# encrypted and enc2 should be the same, except for the salt.

print(enc2)

encryptedString = base64.encodebytes(enc2)

print(encryptedString) # <- this is what can be stored and fetched from mySQL

encrypted = base64.decodebytes(encryptedString) # <- get the bytes back

salt = encrypted[0:SALT_SIZE]
derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                              dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
key = derived[IV_SIZE:]
cleartext = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).decrypt(encrypted[SALT_SIZE:])

print(cleartext)
```

Running this, I get the expected output:

```
b'\xc2\xc6\x81\x9f1\xdb@I\x155\xab6\xe5K\xb5\xfb\xe9\x93\x9c\xd6\xfc\xe1EN?\xdd\xaa'
b'J\x82K\xf6\x10j\x06\xdbK\xd6\xf2\xc2Y\x98\xb9\x16\xb7\x0f\xfa\xb9\x19?\x9ak\xa1\xd5\xc4'
b'SoJL9hBqBttL1vLCWZi5FrcP+rkZP5prodXE\n'
b'Lorem ipsum'
```

The first two lines are the raw bytes, the 3rd line is the Base64 encoded string, which is used to decrypt Lorem imsum from.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. The following line is a problem:

    enc2=b'J\x82K\xf6\x10j\x06\xdbK\xd6\xf2\xc2Y\x98\xb9\x16\xb7\x0f\xfa\xb9\x19?\x9ak\xa1\xd5\xc4'

I'm trying to avoid any manual input. What do you think?

Comment: You haven't provided enough context to resolve the issue. My code snippet showed how you can get binary data encoded into ASCII, which can be stored to, and retrieved from, an SQL string. Not sure where manual input is involved, again, because the context is missing.

Comment: the "enc2=..." was not intended to be part of the solution, but rather a demonstration that the data is still binary, hence not ready for whatever you're doing with it that requires a String. The printout of `encryptedString` shows that it is a valid String.